# Fetch a URL from a Perl script

Tags: perl

I have one Perl script  which  contains  some code to call one URL. URL  pointing to a servlet for storing some data in the data base, based on the parameter passing through the url.I was working with the code below but failed to call the url and fail to store the data in the data base.

```
#!/appl/teamsite/iw-perl/bin/iwperl

for (@ARGV) { printf "%d %s\n", $i++, $_};
my $environment=$ARGV[0];
my $jobid = $ARGV[1];
my $taskID = $ARGV[2];
my $workArea= $ARGV[3];
my $jobDocument = $ARGV[4];

my $url = "http://localhost:7001/JCreationServlet?command=build"."&environment=".$ARGV[0]."&jobID=".$ARGV[1]."&taskID=".$ARGV[2]."&workArea=".$ARGV[3]."&jobDocument=".$ARGV[4];

print "Url is $url\n";

'wget '.$url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if `wget` Library is not installed use `HTTP::Tiny` like this:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new(timeout => 2)->get($url);
```

and print out the return like this to start reusing the response:

```
use JSON;
my $string_response = to_json($response);
print "response is: $string_response\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'wget '.$url;
```

should be backticks, if you want it to be executed

```
`wget $url`
```

Comment: Disco:I have tried with with `wget $url`  but still not able to call the url

Comment: Can you try capturing the output from the backticks and printing it out? e.g my $output = `wget $url`; print "OUTPUT\n$output\n";

Answer (score 0):

You could use ``wget $url``, instead of what you have and this would fix it. However, I recommend using the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) call, as it is better practice:

`system("wget",$url);`

However, if you for some reason need the output, then it would be best to use the backticks and capture it like this:

```
my $response = `wget $url`;
```

Comment: i tried with that  my $url = "http://localhost:7001/JCreationServlet?command=buildassessment"."&environment=".$ARGV[0]."&jobID=".$ARGV[1]."&taskID=".$ARGV[2]."&workArea=".$ARGV[3]."&jobDocument=".$ARGV[4];
print "Url is $url\n";

open(OUTPUT, ">> $fileName")
    || warn("Cannot open $fileName for writing: $!\n");
print OUTPUT "$timeStamp: $0 - $environment - $url - $taskid - $workingdir - $java_version\n";
close(OUTPUT);
system("wget",$url);  but still not working

Comment: I am getting the url correct in the Log but still url is not firing

Answer (score -1):

In your code:

```
'wget '.$url;
```

is simply a string.

Please refer [this](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands) to execute the external commands.